# string red black tree

Tags: string, tree, html-lists

I'm supposed to form a response to a paper I am reading about red black trees, and using relative keys instead of absolute ones.  The point of discussion is supposed to be relating this to strings.

I don't get exactly know how one can use a red black tree for handling strings, when the keys are supposed to be numeric values.

The best I can figure out is that the strings can be sorted by some criteria, and then the index of each string in that ordered list is its key. After that, all operations on the tree are normal ones that are made on a red black tree.

Is this correct?  And if so, what can it be used for?

Comment: One frequently used red black tree variant is string_map, which may be used to maps strings to any sort of value desired, although in any single tree all values must be of the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lexicographical order that you can use as a criterion for comparison between the strings and is implemented in many languages. This lexicographical order is used to order the words of a real dictionary, one of paper.

You need to set this order in order to know if a key must be put to the left of a node (when the key is lesser than the key of the node) or to the right (when is greater)

[Wikipedia entry for lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

So yes you could handle a red black tree with strings as keys.